# Applications for fibonacci series in software paradigm

Tags: theory, fibonacci, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-heap

I was in an interview when I was asked about describing the **application** of **Fibonacci series**.

I knew Fibonacci series are used in some sort of **benchmarking** but I could not come up with a real software/computer application . I tried researching about it . I found they are used in something called **Fibonacci heaps** But I could not find any obvious computer science **application**.

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One the most recognizable application is finding extremums for a given function.

Imagine that you have a function (e.g. y = x^2) and you would like to find its minimum. During this procedure you iteratively reduce the range of values, which contain an extremum.

I would suggest reading [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search). Variant of this algorithm is based on Fibonacci sequnce and it's called **Fibonacci search**.

In addition Fibonacci sequence is used in modelling populations and/or growth of something, e.g. check this article

Finally, there is [an article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168409000449)
in *signal processing* that introduces a link between Kalman filters and Fibonacci sequences.